# Encryption and Decryption of large files using AES algo

Tags: java, image, pdf, encryption, aes

I am encrypting and decrypting large files like video,mp3 and pdf. I am using below algorithm for that. I've tried to download pdf file after decryption of it but it is taking more then one minute for rendering and downloading even file is just 100kb.

Below is my code, how can I solve error and render or download decrypted files faster?

```
public OutputStream encrypt(OutputStream stream) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    OutputStream fos = stream;
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,sks);
    final  CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
    return cos;
}

public InputStream decrypt(InputStream stream) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    InputStream fis = stream;
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
    final CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
    return cis;
    
}
```

I got this error "Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.prepareInputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1005).."

Answer (score 4):

Multiple issues with this code.

1. `"MyDifficultPassw".getBytes()`

This is a bad idea; `getBytes()` converts characters to bytes by decoding them using the 'platform default encoding'. Whilst in some future java that may just be hard-locked to UTF-8, that's not how it works today, which means your actual password (as in, the secret key bytes) depends on the hardware you run it on, which you obviously do not want. Try `.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead, now it'll be consistent no matter what hardware you run it on.

2. `SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");`

Aside from your problem with the charset encoding, there is a larger problem at stake here. Crypto is a lot more complicated than you seem to think it is. There are 3 specific AES ciphers (and 'AES' is a group name for all 3 of these). Each of the 3 AES ciphers requires a different sized secret.

In other words, you can't just take a password, shift it to bytes, and call it a day. You need, specifically, 128 bit, 192 bit, or 256 bits (in bytes, divide by 8: 16, 24, or 32 bytes), and nothing else will do. Your example will usually (depends on that encoding!) result in 16 bytes, which means this works and gets you AES128, but this isn't the usual way to do it. The usual way to do it is to use the password as a 'seed' to create 16, 24, or 32 bytes. This lets the user enter any password of any length instead of forcing it to be 'a password which, if converted to bytes via UTF-8, ends up being precisely 16, 24, or 32 bytes'.

```
byte[] salt = new byte[] {10, 99, 88, 20, 8, 20, 77, 1};
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHMacSHA256");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
```

This will take the password as provided by the user (`password`), and turns that into a 256-bit key using the PBKDF2 algorithm, which is a good idea, and an SO answer is not the right venue to explain why - feel free to search the web for this information. The 'salt' is something that makes it harder to rainbow table the password: It needs to be something hard to guess beforehand, but needs not be particularly secret. You can just hardcode 8 randomly chosen numbers in your source file for it; you'll need it to decrypt as well.

3. `Cipher.getInstance("AES");`

Ciphers, as used to stream data, are *a lot* more complicated than this! There are at least 3 factors:

A. The algorithm. Okay, you got that: AES.

B. padding. These ciphers are *block* ciphers. They operate on blocks. AES (all variants) operates on 16 bytes at a time (NB: EDITED: This used to state it operates on 16/24/32 bytes; this was incorrect, as pointed out in a comment). **It cannot operate on less or more**. So what if your file's size does not nicely divide into 16? What if you have a 45 byte file? A padding algorithm defines what to do then. You need one. `PKCS5Padding` is the usual choice.

C. chaining mode. This is a more complicated beast: At its core, an encryption algorithm is a mathematical formula that converts one number (in-number) into another number (out-number), and the property of the formula is that, if I give you the out-number, you cannot figure out what the in-number was, other than trying every possible number. However, that does mean that the same in-number encrypts to the same out-number every time. This lets someone observing the encrypted data still spot repeated data, even if they don't know what is being repeated. This is a huge problem: For example, a picture of a logo will be trivially recognizable. See [the picture of the pinguin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) on this page for an example of why this is important. To solve this problem you can for example 'mix' the previous block into the next one, and that solves the problem. The NIST recommended mode is GCM. Note that GCM has more or less built-in padding (I'm oversimplifying), so we can use `NoPadding` instead. Another popular but slightly more problematic chaining mode is CBC, which does require padding:

So, let's fix that: `Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");`, or `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");`

Apply the same conversions to the decrypt code and you've solved your problems... somewhat.

> how can I solve error and render or download decrypted files faster?

This sounds like you've messed up on buffering. This has nothing whatsoever to do with your pasted code, but it's the problem with the in/outputstreams you are handing to this method. Many streams need to be written to / read from in large chunks or they are quite slow. Fix this by wrapping them in `BufferedXStream`.

bad:

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("encrypted.txt")) {
    CipherOutputStream cos = encrypt(fos);
     // write data
}
```

good:

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream("encrypted.txt"))) {
    CipherOutputStream cos = encrypt(fos);
     // write data
}
```

Please be aware that, in general, if you don't really know what you are doing, the chance the end result will stand up to even casual attempts at hackery are quite low. There isn't a good solution to this - read up on security, get your code reviewed, try to use more off the shelf stuff instead of handrolling it all. These aren't guarantees, though.

Comment: Thanks for the good description. Kindly note that "AES-256 operates on 32 bytes at a time" is not correct, AES has a block size of 16 byte regardless of the chosen key (length), so I think you better edit your answer, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelFehr of course - my mistake. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you for well description @rzwitserloot, I tried with Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding"); method, but it gives me parameter missing error, do you have idea about that? I tried to generate iv parameter using SecureRandom and used it but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this: but this is working example

```
private IvParameterSpec generateIv() {
    byte[] iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH_BYTE];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
    return new IvParameterSpec(iv);
}

public BigDaddyCryptography(SecretKey secretKey, String transformation) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    this.secretKey = secretKey;
    this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value